How do I replace RelationalModelValidator class of EF Core (C#) with my own class?
Recently I upgraded a .NET solution from .NET 6.0 to .NET 8.0. I started getting errors:

All properties on an entity type must be mapped to unique different columns

I looked up this error on google and ended up with this github issue.
One of the suggestion provided sounds good - this is the solution:
/// <summary>
/// https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30488
/// </summary>
public class AllowSameColumnMultiplePropertiesRelationModelValidator(ModelValidatorDependencies dependencies, RelationalModelValidatorDependencies relationalDependencies) : RelationalModelValidator(dependencies, relationalDependencies)
{
    protected override void ValidateSharedColumnsCompatibility(IReadOnlyList<IEntityType> mappedTypes, in StoreObjectIdentifier storeObject, IDiagnosticsLogger<DbLoggerCategory.Model.Validation> logger)
    {
        try
        {
            base.ValidateSharedColumnsCompatibility(mappedTypes, storeObject, logger);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            var exIsColumnIsAssignedToMoreThanOneProp = ex.Message.Contains("are both mapped to column", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                ex.Message.Contains("but the properties are contained within the same hierarchy", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            if (!exIsColumnIsAssignedToMoreThanOneProp)
                throw;
        }
    }
}

But I am not sure where to place this class and how to force EF Core use this class instead of the original RelationalModelValidator class. Any suggestions on how can I instruct EF Core to use this class instead of RelationalModelValidator class?
Note: I know a column cannot be mapped to two properties under the same hierarchy. But this is a legacy code. The impact of removing this is higher. That is why we are trying to suppress this error.
